# Swift 4.2 not inferring typealias in Protocol

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift-protocols, swift4.2

I have a protocol with a typealias and one var. For Swift 4 it was inferring the typealias actual type when implementing the var attribute within the conforming class, but now I'm trying to move to Swift 4.2 and turns out it is asking me to also declare the typealias.

Protocol:

```
public protocol SystemUnderTestProtocol {
    associatedtype SystemUnderTest
    var sut: SystemUnderTest { get set }
}
```

And this is how my conforming classes look:

```
class SampleTest: SystemUnderTestProtocol {    
    var sut: SampleType!
...
}
```

This used to work well with Swift 4 but now that I'm converting to Swift 4.2 it is complaining about it and can not find not even a word about it in Swift 4.2 changes documentation.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What does "complaining about it" about it mean?

Comment: Sorry, it means that it is asking me to add the typealias declaration in the conforming class because it is not inferring anymore from the attribute declaration

Comment: Interesting. It might be related to the changes to the compiler w.r.t. implicitly unwrapped optionals. Try doing as it says: `typealias SystemUnderTest = SampleType!`

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to avoid. I mean, I don't want to add the declaration in every test class I'm conforming to the protocol. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does it work, though?

Comment: If I declare in every conforming class the typealias with the proper type it does. Just want to avoid doing it, I'm using this protocol in more than 30 test classes

Comment: Currently the IUO-ness of a protocol requirement needs to match the implementation of that requirement, so your requirement needs to be `var sut: SystemUnderTest! { get set }` if it's to be satisfied with an IUO.

Comment: I have the same problem but without the implicitly unwrapped optional. Did you find a solution?